# Primefaces: DataTable reproducing data on sorting

Tags: database, sorting, primefaces, datatable

I got a problem with the Primefaces DataTable. I want to build an Complex Datatable with Filtering and Sorting. I really new to Primefaces so I studied the Examples on Primefaces Showcase.

If you click the first time on the sorting button, the whole list is reproduced and got sorted. On the second click it sorts normally.

The output looks like:

Initial: List has 3 Items.
1st Click: List has 6 Items and is sorted ASC
2nd Click: List has 6 Items and is sorted DES

I'm confused and can't find the mistake. Please help me with this.

Note: I'm using Primefaces 3.4 and JSF 2.1 on Apache Tomcat 7.x

Dashboard.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="frm_dashboard">

    <p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" />

    <p:dataTable var="AntragsDatenObj" value="#{dashboardController.obj_offAntraege}" rowKey="#{AntragsDatenObj.antr_id}" paginator="false" rows="20"  
                 selection="#{dashboardController.selektierterAntrag}" selectionMode="single" id="dt_AntragsDatenObj" style="font-size: 12px; width: 96%">  

        <p: ajax event="rowSelect" update=":frm_dashboard:display" oncomplete="Dialog.show()" />  

        <f:facet name="header">  
            Liste von Anträgen  
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column headerText="ID" sortBy="#{AntragsDatenObj.antr_id}" id="dt_antr_id" style="font-size: 12px;">  
            #{AntragsDatenObj.antr_id}  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Start" sortBy="#{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_startdatum}" id="dt_urlb_startdatum" style="font-size: 12px;">  
            #{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_startdatum}  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Ende" sortBy="#{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_enddatum}" id="dt_urlb_enddatum" style="font-size: 12px;">  
            #{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_enddatum}  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="Länge" sortBy="#{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_laenge}" id="dt_urlb_laenge" style="font-size: 12px;">  
            #{AntragsDatenObj.urlb_laenge}  
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Benutzer" sortBy="#{AntragsDatenObj.user_name}" id="dt_user_name" style="font-size: 12px;">  
            #{AntragsDatenObj.user_name}  
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>

<p:dialog header="Details" widgetVar="Dialog" resizable="false"  
           width="200" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode">  

     <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">  

         <f:facet name="header">  
             Details
         </f:facet>  

         <h:outputText value="ID:" />  
         <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.selektierterAntrag.antr_id}" id="antr_id"/>  

         <h:outputText value="Startdatum:" />  
         <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.selektierterAntrag.urlb_startdatum}" id="urlb_startdatum"/>  

         <h:outputText value="Enddatum:" />  
         <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.selektierterAntrag.urlb_enddatum}" id="urlb_enddatum"/>  

         <h:outputText value="Länge:" />  
         <h:outputText value="#{dashboard.selektierterAntrag.urlb_laenge}" id="urlb_laenge"/>  
     </h:panelGrid>  
 </p:dialog>  

</h:form>
```

MangedBean called DashboardController.java
    package lean.controller;

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import lean.dataobjects.AntragsDatenObj;


@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class DashboardController {

    private List<AntragsDatenObj> obj_offAntraege;

    private AntragsDatenObj selektierterAntrag;

    public List<AntragsDatenObj> getObj_offAntraege() {
        return obj_offAntraege;
    }

    public AntragsDatenObj getSelektierterAntrag() {
        return selektierterAntrag;
    }

    public void setSelektierterAntrag(AntragsDatenObj selektierterAntrag) {
        this.selektierterAntrag = selektierterAntrag;
    }

    public DashboardController() {

        try{

            this.obj_offAntraege = lean.sql.QueryLibrary.getOffneAntraegeMitDaten();

        } catch (Exception e){

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"#DashBoard001 KOMPONENTE: getoffneAntraege ist abgestürzt: ",e.getMessage()));

        }

    }

}
```

DataObject AntragsDatenObj.java 
    package lean.dataobjects;

```
import java.util.Date;


public class AntragsDatenObj {

    private int antr_id;
    private int antr_status;
    private Date urlb_startdatum;
    private Date urlb_enddatum;
    private int urlb_laenge;
    private String user_name;

    public AntragsDatenObj(int antr_id, int antr_status, Date urlb_startdatum, Date urlb_enddatum, int urlb_laenge, String user_name) {
        this.antr_id = antr_id;
        this.antr_status = antr_status;
        this.urlb_startdatum = urlb_startdatum;
        this.urlb_enddatum = urlb_enddatum;
        this.urlb_laenge = urlb_laenge;
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }

    public int getAntr_id() {
        return antr_id;
    }

    public int getAntr_status() {
        return antr_status;
    }

    public Date getUrlb_startdatum() {
        return urlb_startdatum;
    }

    public Date getUrlb_enddatum() {
        return urlb_enddatum;
    }

    public int getUrlb_laenge() {
        return urlb_laenge;
    }

    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }

}
```

Comment: for start change your `public DashboardController()` into `@PostConstruct void public init()` and see if it solve your problem

Comment: I changed it, the result is the same.

Comment: I found out that the constructor is called two times. But Why?

The Dashboard is a component of an Layout Template. I will try to move the Dashboard to the backingBean of the Template Page.

Comment: its inside a `ViewScoped` bean , and for some reason it is being created twice... (SessionScope will solve it... but i think you need to find the reason that the view scope bean is being created twice)

Comment: You mean you defined your bean scope in `faces-config.xml`? no need at all , an annotation inside your class is enough (in JSF2)

Comment: I just added the backing Bean for the Table in the `faces-config.xml` as Session Scoped (without it isn't working at all). I changed the Expression to SessionScoped and that's it. Now it works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for my English.

There is problem in datatable.js line 108

```
sortorder = columnHeader.data('sortorder');

if(sortorder) {
    if(sortorder === 'DESCENDING')
        _self.sort(columnHeader, 'ASCENDING');
    else if(sortorder === 'ASCENDING')
        _self.sort(columnHeader, 'DESCENDING');
}
else {
    _self.sort(columnHeader, 'ASCENDING');
}
```

Initially columnHeader.data('sortorder') is empty even if there is selected sorted column.

**Fix:** on ajax success, for example

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(...);
```

do

```
function() {
    $('.ui-datatable .ui-sortable-column.ui-state-active').each(function() {
        column = $(this);

        if (!column.data('sortorder')) {
            if (column.find('.ui-icon-triangle-1-n')) {
                column.data('sortorder', 'ASCENDING');
            } else if (column.find('.ui-icon-triangle-1-s')) {
                column.data('sortorder', 'DESCENDING');
            }
        }
    });
}
```